# When set the layout visibility as GONE , cant see my spinner which is outside the layout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my XML, I have a 'Select Operator' spinner, then a linear layout which contains some Edit texts and again a 'Select Region' spinner.

Below the layout I have an edit text and a button.
On the button Click even I set the visibility of the layout as GONE or VISIBLE.

When I set the visibility as GONE, I can see the 'Select Operator' spinner, but when I set the visibility as VISIBLE, I can't see my the spinner. I don't know why it is happening.

Can anyone tell me Where the problem exactly is.

My XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/splayout_electricity_OPERATORsp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:entries="@array/operators_electricity"/>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

            android:id="@+id/llayout_electricity_TNEBLAYOUTl"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/splayout_electricity_TNEBREGIONsp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:entries="@array/operators_electricity_REGION"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:hint="Code"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/elayout_electricity_TNEBCODEet" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:hint="Consumer Name"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/elayout_electricity_TNEBCONSUMERNAMEet" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:hint="Contact Number"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/elayout_electricity_TNEBCONTACTNOet" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="Consumer Number (Refer Bill)"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/elayout_electricity_CONSUMERNOet" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="Amount"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/elayout_electricity_AMOUNTet" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/blayout_electricity_RECHARGEbt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:background="#16562e2e"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Pay Bill"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>





My Java file:

    l_TNEB = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.llayout_electricity_TNEBLAYOUTl);
        b_paybill = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.blayout_electricity_RECHARGEbt);

        b_paybill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(l_TNEB.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    l_TNEB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else {
                    l_TNEB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

[image: Can see the Operator Spinner]

[image: Where is my spinner]

Comment: you must give layout_height="wrap_content" for your LinearLayout which is inside of ScrollView.

Comment: Thanks you very much Sir. That solved my problem. How can I accept your comment as a solution ?

Comment: no need for it dude..
your happiness will keep me blessed.. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 'Mahesh B' said,

I set my Linear Layout height as 'Wrap_Content' & Removed Gravity.
That solved my Problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change the layout_height to wrap_content

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:paddingTop="40dp" ///<==i add this 
    android:layout_gravity="center">


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/splayout_electricity_OPERATORsp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:entries="@array/operators_electricity"/>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

        android:id="@+id/llayout_electricity_TNEBLAYOUTl"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/splayout_electricity_TNEBREGIONsp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:entries="@array/operators_electricity_REGION"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="Code"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/elayout_electricity_TNEBCODEet" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="Consumer Name"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/elayout_electricity_TNEBCONSUMERNAMEet" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="Contact Number"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/elayout_electricity_TNEBCONTACTNOet" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Consumer Number (Refer Bill)"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/elayout_electricity_CONSUMERNOet" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Amount"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/elayout_electricity_AMOUNTet" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/blayout_electricity_RECHARGEbt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="#16562e2e"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Pay Bill"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: please elaborate what you want exactly, give me flow

Comment: you want to show Region sppiner after visiblity GONE of editText?

Comment: Sir please read the question again, I have mentioned all the things there. And the issue is solved also. I have posted the solution as Mahesh B said. Thanks.